# Error when trying to update chart data: 'this undefined'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I am working in Vue. My goal is create dynamic stepsize for timeline chart. Here my

```
TimelineChart.vue:
<template>
    <div class="chart chart-timeline">
        <ChartLegend
            :items="legend"
            :allowFilterCreation="allowFilterCreation"
            @highlight="highlighted = $event"
            @toggle="toggleDatasetVisibility($event)"
            @apply-filter="$emit('apply-filter', $event)"
            v-if="legend"/>

        <div class="chart-container" v-show="hasData">
            <canvas ref="chart"></canvas>
          <hr> <hr> <hr> Stepsize Y
          <input type="number" id ="ySteps">
          <hr> Stepsize X
            <input type="number" id ="xSteps">
        </div>

        <h2 class="subtitle is-5" v-if="!hasData">
            No data
        </h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";
import Chart from "chart.js";
import Moment from "moment";

import ChartLegend from "@/components/charts/ChartLegend";
import ChartMixin from "@/components/charts/ChartMixin";

import Deferred from "@/Deferred";

export default {
    props: ["data", "multiMode", "labelConverter", "valueConverter", "allowFilterCreation"],
    components: { ChartLegend },
    mixins: [ChartMixin],
    data() {
        return {
            chart: Deferred.create(),
            highlighted: null
        };
    },
    computed: {
        timeline() {
            return this.data ? _.map(this.data.parameter, it => new Moment(it)) : [];
        },

        keys() {
            return this.data ? _.map(this.data.datasets, it => it.name) : [];
        },
        labels() {
            const converter = this.labelConverter || _.identity;
            return _.map(this.keys, converter);
        },
        datasets() {
            return this.data ? _.map(this.data.datasets, it => it.data) : [];
        },

        datasetCount() {
            return this.datasets.length;
        },

        legend() {
            if (!this.multiMode) {
                return null;
            }

            return _.zipWith(this.keys, this.labels, this.palette, (key, text, color) => ({
                id: key,
                text,
                color: color.normal,
                hidden: _.includes(this.hiddenDatasets, key)
            }));
        },

        chartColors() {
            const highlightIndex = this.highlighted !== null && !_.includes(this.hiddenDatasets, this.highlighted)
                ? _.indexOf(this.keys, this.highlighted)
                : null;

            const colors = [];
            for (const index of _.keys(this.datasets)) {
                const color = this.palette[index];
                if (highlightIndex !== null) {
                    if (index == highlightIndex) {
                        colors.push({ backgroundColor: color.strongMuted, borderColor: color.strong });
                    } else {
                        colors.push({ backgroundColor: color.weakMuted, borderColor: color.weak });
                    }
                } else {
                    colors.push({ backgroundColor: color.normalMuted, borderColor: color.normal });
                }
            }

            return colors;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.chart.resolve(new Chart(this.$refs.chart,  {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                datasets: [],
                labels: []
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: { display: false },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: "time",
                        time: {
                            isoWeekday: true,
                            displayFormats: {
                                hour: "HH:mm",
                                day: "DD-MM",
                                week: "DD-MM",
                                month: "MM-YYYY"
                            }
                        },
                      tooltips: {

                      },
                        ticks: { source: "labels",
                        // stepSize: 2
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: { min: 0, precision: 0,
                          stepSize: 1
                        }
                    }]
                },
                spanGaps: false,
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: item => {
                            const converter = this.valueConverter || _.identity;

                            const label = this.multiMode ? (this.labels[item.datasetIndex] + ": ") : "";
                            return label + converter(this.datasets[item.datasetIndex][item.index]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
// method that change stepsize
       const ySteps = document.getElementById('ySteps');
      ySteps.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        stepSize(this.$refs.chart, e)
      });

       function stepSize(chart) {
         this.chart.resolve.scales.yAxes.stepSize = ySteps.value;
        this.$refs.chart.update()

      }
    watch: {
        data() {
            this.resetDatasetVisibility();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I alter stepsize nothing happen. In debug mode I have noticed the following pattern:
When I create chart 'this.chart' is not undefined. But when I use function stepSize I have an error, that this.chart is undefined. I have read a documentation about it, but I still do not understand how to connect to instance and change the property in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

`this.chart` inside `stepSize` function will not be referring to the `chart` object inside your `data` node, because `stepSize` is not a vue compoenent method, its a javascript function. So `this` wont be refering to your vue scope.

Since you are already passing your `chart` object as a parameter to `stepSize` function as `stepSize(this.$refs.chart, e)`, you can make use of the same inside your `stepSize` function like

```
function stepSize(chart) {
    chart.resolve.scales.yAxes.stepSize = ySteps.value;
    chart.update();
}
```